# Setting UIImageView with an image during runtime causes it to not respect constraints

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS project (Swift), if I set the image of an UIImageView programatically, it does not seem to respect the constraints. I searched around for a solution to this and found some answers stating to set the content mode after the image has been set.

This is the code I have:

```
        //Set imageView
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!);

        //Update imageView mode
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill;
```

However, even when setting aspect fill, the image still spills over the imageview constraints I set. My image is bigger than my image view of course, but I want it to stay within the boundaries. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you comment that lines and set the image in the designer, does it show properly?

Comment: I managed to fix it by setting clipsToBounds, but thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, I fixed it using the following:

```
        //Set imageView
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!);

        //Update imageView mode
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true;
```

This allows my image to cut off.